# Reading a line from a file and printing it

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h" 

main( ) { 
    FILE *fp1; 
    char oneword[100]; 
    char *c;       

    fp1 = fopen("TENLINES.TXT","r"); 
    do { 
        c = fgets(oneword, 100 ,fp1); /* get one line from the file */ 
        if (c != NULL) 
        printf("%s", oneword); /* display it on the monitor */ 
    }  while (c != NULL); /* repeat until NULL */ 

    fclose(fp1); 
}
```

I don't understand why this code need to have a char *c. What does the char *c do here. I tried to change all the 'c' to 'oneword' but it would always have an error. Can you please explain this? 
Thanks.

Comment: if the file doesn't not exist or for some reason you can't open it, this program will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: recommend `#include<stdio.h>`. there are differences between this and your original one.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the documentation of [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html)? It returns `NULL` on failure (e.g. when you reached the end of file).

And of course you should check against failure of [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) like:

```
fp1 = fopen("TENLINES.TXT","r"); 
if (!fp1) 
  { perror("fopen TENLINES.TXT failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` returns a pointer. Where do you want to store it? There should be a pointer defined for this purpose. That's why `char *c` is declared. Also you can't use `oneword` for this, that's already used for storing the line read from file.

Answer (score 1):

[too long for a comment]

Using a while-loop instead of a do-loop would allow you to get around without defining `c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic! */

  FILE * fp1 = fopen("TENLINES.TXT", "r"); 
  if (NULL == fp1)
  {
    result = EXIT_FAILURE; 
    perror("fopen() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    char oneline_if_shorter_then_100_characters[100]; 
    while (NULL != fgets(oneline_if_shorter_then_100_characters, sizeof oneline_if_shorter_then_100_characters, fp1)) /* get one line from the file */ 
    {
      printf("%s", oneline_if_shorter_then_100_characters); /* display it on the monitor */ 
    } /* repeat until fgets had returned NULL */ 

    fclose(fp1); 
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit safer way to handle your requirement using `fgetc()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
FILE *fp1; 
char oneword[100]; 
int c;

int i=0;

if((fp1 = fopen("Newfile.x","r")) <= 0){
    return 1; // File opening failled
}  

  while((c=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF){
      oneword[i]=c;
      i++;

      if(i>=99 || c=='\n'){
            // We are out of buffer OR new line reached
            oneword[i]='\0';
            printf("%s \n",oneword);
            i=0;
      }
   }

    // If some left ; output that too
    oneword[i]='\0';
    printf("%s \n",oneword);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;`  No need for `' '` nor `'\n'` in the `printf()` formats.