# how can i change this code to work without strstr function?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to find every line that has a specific in a text file and count them without using strstr, or getline. how can I change my code to work without it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

FILE * fp;
char * s = argv[1];
int lines = 0, i;
fp = fopen("mytext.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("error\n %d", fp);
    exit(1);
}
size_t lookfor;
char * lines = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
while ((lookfor = getline(&lines, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if(strstr(lines, s) != NULL) {
        lines+= 1;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
printf("the number of lines that include the word 'great' are%d\n", lines);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Without library functions"?  It's going to be pretty much impossible to open the file or read data from it without calling library functions.  Which library functions are you allowed to use?

Comment: oh sorry, i'm only talking about without my strstr and getline

Comment: @AndrewHenle Do you consider system calls to be "library functions"? Because it is simple to read a file using `open`/`read`/`close`.

Comment: What have you got against the function: `strstr()` and the function: `getline()`?

Comment: We are not supposed to do your own homework. Show us what *you* have tried.

Comment: Suggest implementing a state machine and using `fgetc()` to input the file contents

Comment: Have you noticed that the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other problems, it is missing the `string.h` header file

Comment: OT: regarding: `char * s = argv[1];`  The code should never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameter was actually entered by the user

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("error\n %d", fp);`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest using `perror( "my error message" );` as that handles all the above correctly.  Also, the `fp` is a pointer, not an integer, so the statement should be: `printf("error\n %p", (void*)fp);`

Comment: regarding: `char * lines = NULL;
.....
        lines+= 1;`  Strongly suggest using an `int`, initialized to 0 not a `char*`

Comment: Your question lacks some [MCVE]. The given code is not one, it should not compile. So I downvoted the question and voted to close it.

Comment: regarding: `printf("the number of lines that include the word 'great' are%d\n", lines);`  How does the code know that the command line parameter is `great`?  Suggest displaying the actual command line parameter, as pointed to be `s`

Comment: regarding: `while ((lookfor = getline(&lines, &len, fp)) != -1) {` the syntax is: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`  Notice the returned type is `ssize_t` (a signed value) not `size_t` which is an unsigned value AND the comparison is to `-1` which is a signed value.  In programming, details count

Comment: OOPS, I made an error, the `lines` should be a `char *`, initialized to `NULL`.  However, then the statement: `lines+= 1` is nonsense.  Suggest using a `int` variable as a counter

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Of course `open()` is almost always a **library function**.  The "system call" distinction is completely artificial on just about every system.  `open()` is a function in `libc.so`, for example, just like `fopen()` is.  Worse, it's often a misleading distinction, as the mapping from function to system call isn't one-to-one.  Both the `open()` and `fopen()` functions can map to the `openat()` system call.  Labeling `open()`  as a "system call" on POSIX systems is like labeling `OpenFile()` a "system call" on a Windows system. Who does that? Then don't do it on POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are including `<stdio.h>` you are implicitly allowing yourself to use the [standard IO functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)  (If even this is forbidden, how would input or output happen in your program?).

Be sure to look into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) about the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) functions. **Read the documentation of *every* function that you are using**. Later, check also the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

On Linux, `getline` is *declared* in `<stdio.h>` but is not a standard IO function. It is in POSIX. That is documented in the [`getline(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) manual page (obtained with `man getline` command).

So you can, and you probably should, use functions like `fopen` and [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and `fgetc`. On Linux, see also their man page, e.g. [`fgets(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), which reminds you that it is standardized in C99.

A simple approach would be to declare some buffer for your line, e.g.

```
char mylinebuf[128];
```

to *document* that you accept only lines smaller than 128 bytes, and to use

```
char* res = fgets(mylinebuf, sizeof(mylinebuf), fp);
```

Don't forget to test against failure of standard IO functions. In particular, `fopen` [could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608978/841108) fail and `fgets` could also fail.

A more clever approach might mimic what `getline` is doing (so perhaps write your own `mygetline` function), using only [`fgetc(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html).

If you are forbidden to use `strstr` you could write your own `mystrstr` function doing the same (perhaps using [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) if you are allowed to use that, otherwise coding all by yourself). This is basic pointer stuff.

Writing your `mystrstr` above `strchr` is left as an exercise to the reader. And also writing your `mystrchr` using basic pointer operations.

If using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux, always enable all warnings and debug info, so compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). So on Linux learn to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). Avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) -UB- (and your program have several of them, e.g. when invoked without additional arguments). For example

```
     printf("error\n %d", fp);
```

is wrong and UB (and the compiler would have warned you with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`).

You need to improve your code to avoid UB, and that is much more than just changing it to avoid `strstr`.

BTW, in 2019, [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) (in practice), and that might add complication to your program, if you want to be serious (you might want to use [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) if you are allowed to, or else write your `mystrstr` to know about [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and check that your input file contents -or your program arguments- are valid UTF-8; it might not be the case.).

Comment: Where is the change from ASCII to UTF-8 documented?  What about older code that still uses ASCII?

Comment: That change is not documented (and ASCII is not in the C11 standard; you could code in C on IBM mainframes using EBCDIC), but UTF-8 has, in 2019, become common practice.